# Exposing SOAP service using apache Camel and WSDL

Tags: soap, wsdl, apache-camel, cxf, weblogic12c

I have a WSDL file located under src\main\resources\wsdl\ folder and it is having multiple operations defined within it. My application is running on Weblogic 12C server. I'm trying to expose the SOAP web-service using Apache Cammel (version: 2.18.3) with Java DSL -

I have written below code under configuration method of my RouteBuilder class -

```
CxfComponent cxfComponent = new CxfComponent(getContext());
        CxfEndpoint serviceEndpoint = new CxfEndpoint("/soap/Manage_Order", cxfComponent);
        serviceEndpoint.setAddress("http://<IP>:<PORT>/myproject/soap/ManageOrder_Details");
        serviceEndpoint.setServiceClass(
                "Fully qualified service interface name generated from WSDL file using maven with @WebService annotation");
        serviceEndpoint.setEndpointName(<end point name defined in the service class with @WebEndpoint annotation>);
        serviceEndpoint.setDataFormat(DataFormat.MESSAGE);
        serviceEndpoint.setDefaultOperationName("manageOrder");
        getContext().addEndpoint("myServiceEndPoint1", serviceEndpoint);

from("cxf:myServiceEndPoint1").log("Hi, I am here").end();
```

While I'm deploying the application, it is throwing below exception -

```
weblogic.application.ModuleException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: serviceClass must be specified
        at weblogic.application.internal.ExtensibleModuleWrapper.start(ExtensibleModuleWrapper.java:140)
        at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleListenerInvoker.start(ModuleListenerInvoker.java:124)
        at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$3.next(ModuleStateDriver.java:233)
        at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$3.next(ModuleStateDriver.java:228)
        at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:45)
        Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
    Caused By: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: serviceClass must be specified
        at org.apache.camel.util.ObjectHelper.notNull(ObjectHelper.java:311)
        at org.apache.camel.component.cxf.CxfEndpoint.createServerFactoryBean(CxfEndpoint.java:663)
        at org.apache.camel.component.cxf.CxfConsumer.createServer(CxfConsumer.java:70)
        at org.apache.camel.component.cxf.CxfConsumer.<init>(CxfConsumer.java:66)
        at org.apache.camel.component.cxf.CxfEndpoint.createConsumer(CxfEndpoint.java:252)
        Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
```

pom.xml

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
   <artifactId>camel-soap</artifactId>
   <version>2.18.3</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
    <artifactId>camel-cxf</artifactId>
    <version>2.18.3</version>
    <!-- use the same version as your Camel core version -->
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

As the error says, you have not mentioned the service class and endpoint names.
`serviceEndpoint.setServiceClass("Fully qualified service interface name generated from WSDL file using maven with @WebService annotation");
serviceEndpoint.setEndpointName(<end point name defined in the service class with @WebEndpoint annotation>);`

Step 1: Generate the service from your wsdl using wsdl2java command or your choice of IDE.
Step 2: Have that in your code classpath
Step 3: Mention the class name and endpoint names in the above piece of code